# linker warning, changing start of section .stack by 4 bytes

Tags: c, gcc, linker, warnings

I use the arm-none-eabi gcc toolchain to compile code for an Atmel SAM4S microcontroller. The code works, but I get a few linker errors about changing start of section .stack and section .bss.

This is the warnings I get:

`c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.9 2015q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: changing start of section .bss by 4 bytes
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.9 2015q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: changing start of section .stack by 4 bytes
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.9 2015q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: changing start of section .bss by 4 bytes
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.9 2015q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: changing start of section .stack by 4 bytes
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.9 2015q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: changing start of section .bss by 4 bytes
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.9 2015q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: changing start of section .stack by 4 bytes`

After this, compilation completes successfully, and I can flash the code to the microcontroller and it works great.

Should I worry about the warnings?

Edit:
This is my linker script. It is provided by Atmel, i.e., I don't fully understand everything. I tried to read up on the ALIGN command, but I'm still not quite sure what it does in this script.

In my Makefile I have the LD flag ***--warn-section-align -Wl***. If I remove it I don't get the warnings. Is this safe, provided the linker script?

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
SEARCH_DIR(.)

/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00080000 /* flash, 512K */
ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00020000 /* sram, 128K */
}

/* The stack size used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust according to your application. */
STACK_SIZE = 0x3000;

/* Section Definitions */
SECTIONS
{
.text :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sfixed = .;
    KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
    *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
    *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

    /* Support C constructors, and C destructors in both user code
       and the C library. This also provides support for C++ code. */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.init))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __preinit_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    __preinit_array_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __init_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array))
    __init_array_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(0x4);
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __fini_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.fini_array))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    __fini_array_end = .;

    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _efixed = .;            /* End of text section */
} > rom

/* .ARM.exidx is sorted, so has to go in its own output section.  */
PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
.ARM.exidx :
{
  *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
} > rom
PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);

. = ALIGN(4);
_etext = .;

.relocate : AT (_etext)
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate = .;
    *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
    *(.data .data.*);
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate = .;
} > ram

/* .bss section which is used for uninitialized data */
.bss (NOLOAD) :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sbss = . ;
    _szero = .;
    *(.bss .bss.*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = . ;
    _ezero = .;
} > ram

/* stack section */
.stack (NOLOAD):
{
    . = ALIGN(8);
     _sstack = .;
    . = . + STACK_SIZE;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _estack = .;
} > ram

. = ALIGN(4);
_end = . ;
}
```

Comment: Smell like problems into linker script. Maybe alignment.

Comment: How do I investigate this further?

Comment: Check linker script to see where sections should be, and linker map file to see where they actually are.

Comment: all the warnings are saying (and it is due to that one parameter) is that some gap had to be created between sections, because the prior section did not end exactly on the same boundary as the new section is being started.  Suggest removing that one parameter

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
. = ALIGN(8);
```

to the `.relocate` section before `.bss` in your linker script.